# Find a special solution for this equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$w$ is a positive and constant, $b(t)$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $\int_0^{\infty} |b(t)|dt\lt \infty $.
I have to show that   $ y''+(w^2+b(t))y=0 $    has a solution $f(t)$  such that 
$$\ lim_{t\to\infty} \{[f(t)-sin (wt)]^2+[f'(t)-wcos(wt)]^2\}=0$$holds.
I can change it to a two dimensional system and then trace of coeficients matrix is zero then derivatives of determinant of fundamental matrix is zero too, but these facts can't help me to solve my problem!

Comment: @LutzL sorry ! You are right, i will edit it

Comment: One could probably start by constructing solutions $y_n$ for $y_n(2^n\pi/w)=0$, $y_n'(2^n\pi/w)=w$ and try to prove, via Gronwall and related estimates, that $y_n(0)$ and $y_n'(0)$ converge, and that the solution for the IVP with the limit points as initial values is the searched for $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $B(t)=\int_t^\infty b(s)\,ds$ so that $B'(t)=-b(t)$. By assumption, this is a bounded function that converges asymptotically towards $0$.

To avoid the uncontrollabe derivative $b=-B'$, construct a first order system using $u=y'-By$, 
\begin{align}
u'=y''-B'y-By'=-w^2y-B(u+By)
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{align}
y'&=+u+By\\
u'&=-w^2y+B^2y-Bu
\end{align}

---

Set $z=e^{-iwt}(u+iwy)$, then
\begin{align}
|z(t)-w|^2&=\Bigl|(u(t)+iwy(t))-we^{-iwt}\Bigr|^2
\\[0.5em]&=\Bigl(y'(t)-B(t)y(t)-w\cos(wt)\Bigr)^2
+w^2\Bigl(y-\sin(wt)\Bigr)^2
\end{align}
which is an equivalent distance so that when $z(t)\to w$, then the given distance will too converge to zero.

---

The differential system now translates to
$$
z'=e^{-iwt}(u'+iwy'-iwu+w^2y)=e^{-iwt}(B^2y-Bu+iwBy)
$$
Select some $ε>0$ and a corresponding $T$ so that $|B(t)|\le ε$ for $t\ge T$. Then 
$$
(|z(t)-w)|)'\le |z'(t)|\le C·B·|z(t)|\le C·B·(|z(t)-w|+w)
$$
for $t\ge T$ (with $C=(1+ε/w)$).

---

Integrating a la Grönwall with $A(t)=\int_T^t C·B(s)\,ds$ gives
$$
\left(e^{-A(t)}(|z(t)-w|+w)\right)'
=e^{-A(t)}\left(|z'|-C·B(t)·(|z(t)-w|+w)\right)
\le0
$$
which implies, as $A(t)\le B(T)·(t-T)$,
$$
|z(t)-w|\le (|z(T)-w|+w)·e^{C·ε·(t-T)}-w
$$
as my best ideas so far.